# Summing/Appending Entires Along an Array or Matrix axis until numerical condition is met

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, iteration

Afternoon.  Per the title-I'm having some issues summing entries along an an axis of an array and appending associated entries in the same row to a seperate list.

Background.  I'm using the SVD numpy function to determine the singular values and right singular vectors of an arbitrary array. I have created a numpy array with columns of the singular vectors and associated values.  in the context of the problem I am working on-I'd like to compute the sum across the array create a loop that sums entries along the row until the sum through iteration  is at least 90 percent (maybe only three of the 8 entries account for this so I'd like to create a list with those entries only and their associated right singular vectors) I have tried to simplify my problem for now and have only tried working on a function that computes the above sans returning the associated vector.  Here's a quick rundown of what I've tried

## create the array holding the singular values, in this case s.  svd function returns 3 arrays in total

`create the tuples of singular values and associated right singular vectors.`

```
for i in range(len(s)):
singular_pairs=[np.abs(s[i]),v[:,i]]

u,s,v=svd(the matrix)



def variance_threshold(x):
#initialize the sum value, create the empty array of singular values that       will be kept

  x = 0
  kept_eigenvalues=[]
  #condition

  while x < (.9*sum(s)):
    if i <len(s):
      x=s[i]+s[i+1]
      kept_eigenvalues.append(x)
    else:
      break
  return kept_eigenvalues
```

Let me know if this is salvageable or if I should move towards nesting for loops.  much appreciated!

Comment: correct the indents!

Comment: ag.  that was just an editing error on my part in typing here.  went ahead and fixed it.  thanks!

Comment: Appending to a list like this is perfectly fine, especially if you don't know how many items you'll end up.

Comment: good to know I'm on the right track.  for some reason i'm getting a blank list after calling the function which is a bit interesting.  Might just be a slight mistsep in my indexing